# How to pass and get parameter with routerLink in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to pass a value with url using routerLink. And read that value on another page. 
Like I have product list. On select of first record the id of that record pass to product detail page. After read that productId I want to show detail of that product.

So How can I pass and get the parameter?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm assuming  you have some code like this:

```
{ path: 'product/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent }
```

in ProductList template

```
<a [routerLink]="['/product', id]">Home</a>
```

or

```
<a [routerLink]="['/product', 5]">Home</a>
```

where `id` is a variable, maybe you got it in a loop.

in ProductDetailComponent:

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router
) {}
ngOnInit() {

  this.route.params
    // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.yourProductService.getProductById(+params['id']))
    .subscribe((product) => this.product = product);
}
```

Router document: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: I get the error Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Params>' .

Answer (score 12):

Use `routerLink` on your `a` tag for passing it by url.

```
[routerLink]="['yourRouteHere', {'paramKey': paramValue}]
```

To get it you need to use `ActivatedRoute` service. Inject it into your component and use it's subscribe method. Here my `route` is the **injected service**

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   const id = Number.parseInt(params['paramKey']);
}
```

If you want to get parameters from the **route segment** use `.params`, else if you want from **query string**, use `.queryParams`

Comment: but what about `[routerLink]="['yourRouteHere', {'paramKey': {'key':'value'}}]`

Comment: @suren add the  double inverted comma[routerLink]="['yourRouteHere', {'paramKey': paramValue}]"

Comment: this solution is better as you don't require to create any new path!

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

Step-1: In routing module

```
{ path: 'product/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent }
```

Step-2: Send the value to routing

```
<a [routerLink]="['/product', id]">Home</a> //say, id=5
```

Step-3: Read the value in ProductDetailComponent

First inject `ActivatedRoute` from `'@angular/router` and say `route` is the injected service. Use the below code inside `ngOnInit()` method to read it.

```
id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Suppose your url is  **http://mit.edu/dashboard** and desired result is
>      **http://mit.edu/dashboard/user?id=1** then use below code

```
<a [routerLink]="['user']" [queryParams]="{id: 1}" </a>
```

> 2. Suppose your url is **http://mit.edu/dashboard** and your desired result is **http://mit.edu/user?id=1** then use below code ["Difference is **/Dashobard**" missing here from url]

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user']" [queryParams]="{id: 1}" </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this in `.html`

```
[routerLink]="['/trips/display/' + item.trip, {'paramKey': 'application'}]"
```

and in `.ts` you can use this to recover the params

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
const param = this.route.snapshot.params['paramKey'];
```