# Access parameters from URL using Angular

Tags: angular

I want to access the parameters from url in Angular 2. I use ActivatedRoute service instance which has the property of Params, Params has the property **_value** which has the parameters but when tried to access it in Visual Code couldn't why is that ?

[image]

Comment: How are you accessing it?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201703/how-to-pass-and-get-parameter-with-routerlink-in-angular-2) and try this below.

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
this.id = params['id']; //Assume id is your parameter name                    
});
```